# How to authenticate a web service for both "browser" and "non-browser" clients?

Tags: authentication, cookies, client, access-token

My web service expects both `browser` and `non-browser` clients. And I use token based authentication to make the service `stateless`.

I store the token as cookies because I want when some Ajax calls initiated from the web page, the token is sent along `automatically by the browser`.

But for a non-browser client, how to handle cookie? Do I just manage the cookie as a plain HTTP header?

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way to do this on a non-browser client is to use something like the OAuth2 protocol. This protocol was designed to securely handle stuff like this for both browser AND non-browser clients.

Here's how it works:

- Your service exposes an OAuth2 endpoint, typically `/oauth/token`.
- Your client sends a form-encoded POST request to `/oauth/token`, specifying what 'type' of OAuth2 the client is using. In the case of a non-browser client, you'd most likely supply `grant_type=password` in the body of your POST request.
- You also include your username/password to authenticate yourself.

What your client will then get BACK, is an Access Token / Refresh Token that should be securely stored on your client.

If your client is a mobile device like iOS, you'd store the Access / Refresh Tokens in the iOS keychain -- if you're on Android, you'd store those tokens in Shared Preferences. Either way -- these are 'secure' storage locations meant for holding confidential information like tokens.

Then, when you need to use those tokens to authenticate against your service, you can simply POST to your API with that token, and bam, you will be authenticated.

This is the ideal way to handle token stuff in most situations. I'm the author of an authentication library in Node called [express-stormpath](https://github.com/stormpath/express-stormpath), and this is how I do it as well.